# VBA functions in MS Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA, and I have a question, i.e I have a mathematical function 1 + 2x¹ + 3x² + 4x³ + ... +10x⁹ and I need to resolve it into two ways:

1. I can use raising operations(analog pow in Pascal) and IF statement;
2. without rising operations and IF statement...

I have tried this one:

```
Public Function test(x)


test = 1 + 2*x^1 + 3*x^2 + 4*x^3 + 5*x^4 + 6*x^5 + 7*x^6 + 8*x^7 + 9*x^8 + 10*x^9


End Function
```

but I think it returns the wrong answer - 2441406 with calling `=test(5)`

So can anyone give any advice, or help with my problem?

Comment: If you want the series of x raised to the power of 0 to 9 then the answer is correct. Your slightly iffy prose of describing what you want makes me confused (by `10x9` do you mean 10 times x to the power of 9 or what?). Also, forgive me but I am not sure what you mean by `IF statament; 2 - without rising operations and IF statement.`

Comment: If 2441406 is the wrong answer, then what is the right answer?

Comment: I see your edited question but my queries remain. Your function is returning the series of, for i = 0 to 9, Sum ( (i + 1) * x ^ i ). If that is not what you want then perhaps you need to define the algebraic series you want more clearly.

Comment: @Cor_Blimey I mean 10*x^9;

Comment: @ArtursGasjulis what you posted isn't valid vba so...there should be a `*` multiplication operator between the two operands. E.g. `10 * x ^ 9`. I don;t really understand your posted code because it gives a syntax error.

Comment: @Cor_Blimey, but I had an error Sub or function not defined and it points to the Sum

Answer (score 4):

If you can't use VBA for this, there is a formula solution.  Assuming your variable `x` is in cell A1, you would use this formula in another cell (I used B1):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ROW($1:$10)*A1^(ROW($1:$10)-1))
```

When A1 = 5, it returned 23803711 as expected.

Answer (score 3):

You will need `*` as the multiper:

```
Public Function test(x)
    test = _
         1 _
      + 2 * (x ^ 1) _
      + 3 * (x ^ 2) _
      + 4 * (x ^ 3) _
      + 5 * (x ^ 4) _
      + 6 * (x ^ 5) _
      + 7 * (x ^ 6) _
      + 8 * (x ^ 7) _
      + 9 * (x ^ 8) _
      + 10 * (x ^ 9)
End Function
```

Comment: indeed it does have the wrong syntax, so I am interested as to how it gave any answer let alone 2441406 :). It would give a syntax error without your correction.

Comment: There Cor_Blimey explained he did the equation somewhere else and give the incorrect answer.  So I think there are 2 questions here indeed: 1) Why is the code not working, 2) If the code works is the equation correct.  The correct answer seems to be 23803711 by the way

Comment: @alex, yeap, correct answer is 23803711, but i can't solve this by VBA (

Comment: The answer 2441406 is when you do the equation without multiplying the prefix (i.e. x^1 + x^2 + x^3 ...)

Comment: @guitarthrower just for context, several edits have been made in between this answer and your comment. I agree that now the syntax in the OP is correct. Which begs the question as to what the OP was originally trying. Which is also moot as Alex's answer gives the result the OP is looking for. For OP: I have verified this will compile and solve your issue giving your desired 23803711 answer.

Comment: @ArtursGasjulis can you clarify what do you mean by can't solve it?

Comment: @Cor_Blimey Yep saw that after I posted :) I updated the code in Alex's answer for the full function. Hopefully that will help.

Comment: @guitarthrower thanks for the editing, yet the brackets are not needed , computer is smart to do multiply before addition =D

Comment: @Alex I agree they are not needed, but given the confusion of the OP and the request they may help clarify what is happening first in the formula.

Comment: Roger that, I didn't think from the OP's pov

Comment: @guitarthrower what is the `2` in the `test2` supposed to mean? Will it even compile?

Comment: It should be test instead of test2.  You end up more typo by throwing too many guitar =D